# Undestanding SVM

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

I am the moment trying to understand how SVM works.. 
I understand the concept of finding a seperating hyperplane with the highest margin, but i do not understand how it works in mathmatically.  Mor precisely, why is the  hyper plane depicted as it is, and how does one find the one with the greatest margin?

Comment: [SVM: Support Vector Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (for those who don't recognize the initialism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of how this works described step by step on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Support_vector_machine&oldid=720608133).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/637937)

Comment: I changed it to a permalink, as I do not think wikipedia is going down any time soon.